# EAAccessory protocolstrings issue

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, eaaccessory

> I am trying to connect my iPhone to a custom bluetooth device. And I am following the EAdemo. Running the app, I am not getting null in **protocolstrings**. Whereas, sometimes I do get the object when I debug the app. Any insight on why this happens?
>
> Could be this a timing problem?
>
> Its being inconsistent...

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the device itself. There was no issue with code. Thanks.